# How to use Ajax to update RenderBody()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to work with ajax in order to update only a partial view and not the whole view. In the following example I want to refresh the page-content section.

this is my layout.html.

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="effect">
    @Html.Partial("_head")

    <div class="boxed">
        <section id="content-container">
            @if (ViewData["Errors"] != null)
            {
                <div class="panel" style="background-color:white;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            Page title
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            <div id="page-content" class="container">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

           </section>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Partial view _head contains the menu with href links for example:

```
<a id="a1" href="">Menu Item 1</a>
```

In layout I am trying to use the following:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#a1").click(function () {
            A1();
    });

        function A1( ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PartialViewMethodFromController", "HomeController")',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#page-content').html(response);
                }
            });
        } 
});
</script>
```

And my HomeController

```
    public ActionResult PartialViewMethodFromController()
    {

        var model = service.GetAll();
            return PartialView("PartialViewMethodFromController", model);

}
```

It kinda works - the partialview is refreshing for a moment and the partialview is show correctly and then the whole page goes on and refreshes. 
Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: Because your not cancelling the default redirect of the link - `$("#a1").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); A1(); });`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Just a last question - is it overall a good solution to use this? I mean refreshing the renderbody section while navigating through the links.

Comment: I do not know enought about your app, but its fine and improves performance because only part of the page is updated. but if you have multiple links, the the links would be `<a href="#" class="menu" data-url="@Url.Action(....)">...</a>` and you would have only one script - `$('.menu').click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); $('#page-content').load(url); });`

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot again.